# Obtaining reddit data

Tags: web-scraping, reddit

I am interested in obtaining data from different reddit subreddits. Does anyone know if there is a reddit/other api similar like twitter does to crawl all the pages?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, reddit has an API that can be used for a variety of purposes such as data collection, automatic commenting bots, or even to assist in subreddit moderation.

There are a few places to discover information on reddit's API:

- [github reddit wiki](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) -- provides the overview and rules for using reddit's API (follow the rules)
- [automatically generated API docs](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api) -- provides information on the requests needed to access *most* of the API endpoints
- [/r/redditdev](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev) -- the reddit community dedicated to answering questions both about reddit's source code and about reddit's API

If there is a particular programming language you are already familiar with, you should check out the [existing set of API wrappers](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers) for various languages. Despite my bias (I am the package maintainer) I am quite certain [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/wiki), for python, has support for the largest number of reddit API features.

Answer (score 15):

Note that if you are only reading data, and not interested into posting back to reddit, you can get quite a bit of data from the json feeds associated with each subreddit.  With this method, you don't need to worry about an API at all -- you simply request the relevant json file and parse it in your language of choice.

Here's an example URL that will return a json object containing the hot posts from the Justrolledintotheshop subreddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Justrolledintotheshop/top.json

In place of top, you can use `hot`, `new`, or `controversial`.  When using top, you can add `?t=day` to the end of the url to specify the top post for the day.  Other valid values are `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month`, `year`, or `all`.

Answer (score 1):

To parse JSON data from **reddit** with **ajax/javascript**.

Reddit has **CORS** enabled for GET requests.

Here as example, parse the last **videos** from reddit in JSON format:

```js
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
xhr.open("GET","https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/.json",true)
xhr.send(null)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.status === 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

To go deeper, check out this question:

[Change youtube video ID without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138693/change-youtube-video-id-without-page-reloading)