# Change YouTube video ID without page reloading

Tags: javascript, youtube, polymer, bookmarklet

This question is about scripting the main YouTube site, client side from JavaScript.

While it looks easy as a click, I found no way to change the current video by a new *non in context* video ID without reloading.

This seems to be related with the `polymer` library in use, with a lot of shadow dom and some special behavior.

Here is the context: I am making for my own use a bookmarklet that load videos from the **reddit json api**, which supports CORS calls.

So far so good, I can load many videos, image previews and links into the YouTube sidebar, with this simple enough handcrafted script.

Bookmarklet to call the script:

```
javascript:void%20function(){target=document.getElementsByTagName(%22script%22)[0],inj=document.createElement(%22script%22),inj.src=%22https://webdev23.github.io/reddube/reddube.js%22,target.appendChild(inj)}();
```

This bookmarklet is loading into the DOM a js file, that is parsing the json api to get what I need.

Here is the [content of the called file](https://github.com/webdev23/reddube):

```
var reds = ["/r/videos","/r/unknownvideos","/r/DeepIntoYouTube","/r/newsreels","/r/fullmoviesonyoutube","/r/SF_Videos","/r/classicfilms","/r/Documentaries","/r/artdocumentaries","/r/ShowsonYT","/r/YTPL","/r/NotTimAndEric","/r/youtubehaiku","/r/PlayItAgainSam","/r/ObscureMedia","/r/360video","/r/AccidentalComedy","/r/amibeingdetained","/r/ArtisanVideos","/r/AwfulCommercials","/r/bestofworldstar","/r/cringe","/r/CommercialCuts","/r/contagiouslaughter","/r/cookingvideos","/r/curiousvideos","/r/deepintoyoutube","/r/documentaries","/r/educativevideos","/r/FastWorkers","/r/fightporn","/r/FuckingWithNature","/r/fullmoviesonyoutube","/r/happycrowds/","/r/idiotsfightingthings","/r/lectures","/r/mealtimevideos","/r/motivationvideos","/r/ObscureMedia","/r/playitagainsam","/r/Prematurecelebration","/r/PublicFreakout","/r/Roadcam","/r/streetfights","/r/sweetjustice","/r/TheWayWeWereOnVideo","/r/trailers","/r/UnexpectedThugLife","/r/videoporn","/r/vids","/r/vines","/r/virtualfreakout","/r/woahtube","/r/listentothis/","/r/Tekno/","/r/reggae/","/r/RootsReggae","r/ska","/r/dub","/r/hip_hop","/r/treemusic/","/r/stonerrock/","/r/frenchrap/","/r/trance/","/r/minimal/"]  
var rview = ["","/new/","/rising/","/controversial/","/top/"]  
related.innerHTML = "<div style='filter: sepia(38%) invert(100%) saturate(100%) brightness(1) grayscale(0%) hue-rotate(360deg) contrast(100%)'><span id='subR' data-ccc='25' style='color:white;background:#141e1b;font-size:1.44em;width:20px'></span><input type='range' value='0' max='64' id ='redR' style='float:right;width:230px' onchange='redList.innerHTML=\"\";redd(this.value)'><br><span onclick='redList.innerHTML=\"\";' style='float:right;margin:3px 0 0 0'><button id='rflt' data-filter='0' onclick='this.dataset.filter=0;redd(redR.value)'>hot</button><button onclick='rflt.dataset.filter=1;redd(redR.value)'>new</button><button onclick='rflt.dataset.filter=2;redd(redR.value)'>rising</button><button onclick='rflt.dataset.filter=3;redd(redR.value)'>controversial</button><button onclick='rflt.dataset.filter=4;redd(redR.value)'>top</button></span><hr /><hr /><hr /><hr /><hr /><tr><br></div><div id='redList'>"

function redd(it){
 console.log(it)    
 console.log(reds[1])
 
 subR.innerHTML = reds[it]
  
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
  xhr.open("GET","https://www.reddit.com"+reds[it]+rview[rflt.dataset.filter]+".json?limit=200",true)
  xhr.send(null)
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
    if(this.status === 200) {
     
      vids = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) 
   
      cc = subR.dataset.ccc

    for (var j=0;j<=cc;j++){
     try{ 
      var rt = vids['data']['children'][j]['data']['title'],
      rl = vids['data']['children'][j]['data']['url'],
      rp = vids['data']['children'][j]['data']['secure_media']['oembed']['thumbnail_url'],
      rr = vids['data']['children'][j]['data']['permalink']     
      
      redList.innerHTML += "<td><a href='"+rl+"'><img style='width:150px;height:auto;max-width:120px' src='"+rp+"'></img></a><span style='max-width:68%;float:right;text-align:center;font-size:1.23em'><a class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-compact-video-renderer' style='text-decoration:bold;font-size:1.23em;text-align:left;min-width:260px' href='"+rl+"'>"+rt+"</a><a target='blank' style='text-decoration:bold;color:black;float:right' href='https://www.reddit.com"+rr+"'>⮊</a></span></td><br>"
     }catch(e){console.log(e)}
     
    }   
      }
    }
  }
}

related.innerHTML += "</tr><button onclick='redList.innerHTML=\"\";redd(redR.value)'>Load more</button>"
redd(0)
 
window.onscroll = function() {
  var d = document.documentElement,
      offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight,
      height = d.offsetHeight
  
  if (offset >= '2000' && offset <= '2300') {

     subR.dataset.ccc = 25
     
  }

  if (offset >= '2000' && offset <= '2100') {

     subR.dataset.ccc = 50
     
  }
  
  if (offset >= '3400' && offset <= '3500') {
   
     subR.dataset.ccc = 100
     
     
  }
  if (offset >= '5400' && offset <= '5500') {
  
     subR.dataset.ccc = 150
     
  }
  
  if (offset >= '7400' && offset <= '7500') {
   
     subR.dataset.ccc = 200
     
  }
}
```

[image]

At this stage, clicking a link is just reloading the page.

I tried many things, changing the content of elements, try to alter the "next" recommended video.

Also creating a link in the DOM, isn't working, it is reloading.

**Here is the problem in a simple way:**

Let's say you are in this YouTube page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgGzAKP_HuM

From the console, how to load *this non related id* `-q7ZVXOU3kM`
into the page, just like a link click on the recommendation sidebar?

The following is NOT working: `Visibility monitor is not attached`

```
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
 xhr.open("GET","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q7ZVXOU3kM",true)
 xhr.send(null)
 document.body.innerHTML = xhr
```

[image]

**18 OF MARCH 2018: END OF BOUNTY: QUESTION UNRESOLVED!!!**

This is a fairly complex stuff.

The dom content is constantly changing at every reload, and it include recommended video id into the changing scripts. This id's only are allowed to use the ajax capabilities.

This recommendation are changing at any reload, but they are coming back in loop.

I am building a tool to deeply analyze differences, and I found many interesting things, much more that I was searching.

This topic isn't close!

**It's not about the destination, it's about the journey.**

[image]

Comment: *"Also creating a link in the DOM, isn't working, it is reloading."* So if you dynamically create a link then append it, the page reloads? If you are able to inject an iframe, I believe that this is feasible.

Comment: Yes, when altering the dom, elements non in context acts as regular, with a document reload. I think there is some js to pull in first. The good parts is we can do ajax calls, because we are on the same domain^ I tried the iframe way, or just calls the full document html in an hidden div and replace the current one, but it fails. This is why i don't provide code, no success so far!

Comment: Provide at least 2 working yt ids or if you already have please direct me to them.

Comment: Updated, thanks it will be useful.

Comment: You can use **postMessage API**, I've made a [primitive playlist](https://embed.plnkr.co/jSARI280NoK7PUqQGO1t/) from an array of yt ids.

Comment: Absolutely, we are on the same origin.

Comment: See updated comment for link, the first position video is dead but the others are still live. click the YT logo to open and close iframe

Comment: This isn't what i am looking for, but i am going to try to use this approach, will leave news if any success. I think i won't be able to load comments this way.

Answer (score 2):

it appears that there is no (public) api for the player on youtube :/ 
but there is one for the iframe youtube player - there you can just call

```
player.loadVideoById("Vw4KVoEVcr0", 0, "default");
```

for details see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById

That is a quick example I found where you see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/8bpQ8/1/

If you really want to directly modify youtube you probably have to dig around in the obfuscated code :/ I tried to find it... but it's obfuscated so you can't easily find it. And even if you find it it will be something like `_yt_player.h.xx.xy.h()`. Also whenever it will be generated new (and maybe even it is even different for countries... ) your code may break.

Also, it appears to have nothing to do with polymer as there is a player element but it does not have a function to change the video. Apparently, it is only to place the player... control still resides within the js function.

I'm sorry to not have any better news - maybe someone else knows more.

Comment: This is not matching my question, i can't say it resolve the problem. I have had further info.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the videoId being `YgGzAKP_HuM`if you inspect the `<video>` you will see something like that:

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/8e1ef216-1901-ec44-9b76-ea8276e368c6"></video>
```

You need to find how youtube create their [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Blob) from a videoId and change the `src` of the player if you want to avoid reloading the page.

But maybe for your project you should think about using the [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById). It does exactly what you want. And if you want to stay on youtube.com you can replace the youtube original player by an `iframe` in the DOM.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am looking to change the whole page, including comments, titles. Here i am going to end-up with a video in the wrong context! It would be easier to replace directly the video by an iframe on this case!

Comment: Then maybe you should also look at the all youtube API about [comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) and [comment treads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads)

Answer (score -1):

Trying to find a hidden YouTube API is incredibly difficult and it's likely that the next tweak Google makes to YouTube will break your bookmarklet and you'd be back where you started. I think you should take another route altogether. Google provides an API to create, delete, and otherwise manipulate YouTube playlists here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists.

If you’ve never used YouTube API before, see here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Then, (finally!) you can write some JavaScript that creates YouTube playlists from reddit at your command.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The api is for embeding only.

Comment: @Cryptopat Where does it say that?

Comment: No lies, i am not going to use the api, therefore dive in it. This is my opposite goal.

Comment: Not accusing you of lying, it's just that I want know where it says "for embedding only". It's fine if you don't use the API, that's your decision. Good luck with your bookmarklet thingy.

Comment: Sorry, i would like to mean "I won't going to lie, i don't know!"